# Batch Exporting Layouts to PDF in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, export, arcgis-pro, pdf, layouts

Is there a way to batch export layouts in an ArcGIS Pro document to a specific format?

For example exporting all layouts to PDF in a file directory.

This was possible with multiple MXDs using python with Desktop, however I haven't found a way to do this with Pro.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I use to do this. the print statement is completely unnecessary though, especially since this is run as a script tool in ArcGIS Pro.

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
figFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

for lyt in aprx.listLayouts():
    print(" {0} ({1} x {2} {3})".format(lyt.name, lyt.pageHeight, lyt.pageWidth, lyt.pageUnits))
    lyt.exportToPDF(figFolder + "\\" + lyt.name + ".pdf")
```

Answer (score 4):

As [commented by @KHibma](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271468/batch-export-layouts-in-arcgis-pro#comment432232_271468) with respect to the `listLayouts` method of the APRX object:

> Combine the 2 code samples (near the bottom) from here:
>   http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm and
>   you'll export all layouts in a project to PDF

Answer (score -1):

I had to take out the figFolder = line from lynryd's code above. I was getting an error telling me the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>

...***BUNCH OF STUFF I DELETED FROM ERROR MESSAGE***...

  RuntimeError: Object: Parameter index out of range for GetParameterAsText
```

Comment: Following up on [Ron Santos answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/329077/107424), [lynyrd's script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/315974/107424) is fine. Using the ```.GetParameterAsText() ```
method implies that you're going to import the script to your toolbox and set up a parameter definition, so when you run the tool you're prompted for the output location of your choice. I'm new to this so I was confused at first by the same error. Found the (obvious in retrospect) solution in another post: https://community.esri.com/thread/29926 _(Hope I didn't break any major rules by adding another